# Put my bibfile into the root directory of MikTeX but bibtex doesn't find it

Tags: bibtex, miktex, paths

I have a lot of different folders with different projects and different **.tex** documents. For all of them I am using the same bib-file (**mainbib.bib**). Since it gets a bit tedious to always keep the bib-file in the same folder as the **.tex**, I thought I could try the do the following:

I copied my **mainbib.bib** file into the the root's directory of MikTeX's bibtex folder, that would be something like

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\bibtex\bib\bibtex

since - at least I thought so - MikTeX would look into this folder while searching for the file (before it eventually would find it in the same folder as my **.tex**). But it doesn't find the **mainbib.bib** file. Is there anything I did wrong or does this approach not work at all?

I am using Windows 10 and MikTeX 2.9 (TeXworks) and for typesetting *latexmk*.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 
\parindent0mm  
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed, color}

\makeatother
\makeindex 
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\cite{test}

\bibliography{mainbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: any additional info in the log-files?

Comment: @naphaneal nothing which would make it any clearer...except that sometimes it looks in **C:\Program Files (x86)** and sometimes in **C:\Users\user190080\AppData\Roaming** - so alternating directories and I only tried to put the file into the first one...might give a shot in the second as well.

Comment: You'd better create  some`bibfiles` subdirectory  of your working directory, or in your `local`  texmf root. You should never put whatever in the main root: it might be deleted on updates.

Comment: @Bernard That's definitely a good point - for now, I just wanted to test whether it actually works or not. Am I right that the working directory depends on what editor I actually use, like TeXworks?

Comment: For TeXworks, I don't know, as I don't use it. For my actual editor (WinEdt), I can choose the default startup folder.

Comment: You need to update the FNDB in admin mode if you put the bib there. But it is better to use a local texmf tree. Create localtexmf/bibtex/bib and add localtexmf as a new root in miktex settings.